# How to show a success message in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am a beginner and learning ASP.Net MVC web development. I am stuck at one place.

I have a reset password window. If user successfully resets the password I want him to redirect to the same page but I want a "Password Reset Successful" message to be on top. It can be an alert or something. Just user should know that password has been reset. But I don't know how to achieve this. Below is what I have till now.

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ViewResult WidgetResetPassword(ResetPasswordMV data)
    {
        bool isValid = false;

        isValid = ModelState.IsValid;

        // verify the 2 password match
        if (isValid && !data.NewPassword.Equals(data.ConfirmNewPassword))
        {
            isValid = false;
            ModelState.AddModelError("ConfirmNewPassword", "Passwords doesn't match.");
        }

        if (isValid)
        {
            //setting the correct tenant id
            if (Session[Constants.SESSION_USER_KEY] != null)
            {
                UserMV authenticatedUsers = (UserMV)Session[Constants.SESSION_USER_KEY];

                data.UserId = authenticatedUsers.Id;
            }

            ResetPasswordHelper.Save(data);
        }
        return View(data);
    }
```

**My .cshtml file:**

```
@model ResetPasswordMV
@using SIM_Obj.ModelViews;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Reset Password";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

@*    <div id="ResetPasswordWidget" class="form-horizontal">*@
        <div id="ResetPasswordWidget" class="form-horizontal-width-inherit">
            <h3>Reset Password</h3>
            <hr/>

            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})

            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserId)

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OldPassword, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OldPassword, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OldPassword, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewPassword, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewPassword, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewPassword, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmNewPassword, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmNewPassword, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmNewPassword, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Reset Password" class="btn btn-default"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

I want to be able to add something like:

```
<p class ="alert alert-success"> <strong>Success! </strong>Your Password has been successfully changed.</p>
```

Question 1: How to get this

to be displayed when password is reset.

Question 2: Currently I am doing `return view(data)` in the controller. Is it necessary.

Question 3: Can I use something like partialview. I am beginner. Please guide me.

Comment: One question per post. What person will do if he can answer for an example question 1 and 3, but not 2.

Comment: They all are reated I thought.. Nevermind.

Comment: I was just trying to put what was going on in my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a property like `ShowMessage` to your model and set it if the reset was successful.

Change the view to

```
@if (model.ShowMessage)
{
    <p class="alert alert-success"> <strong>Success! </strong>Your Password has been successfully changed.</p>
}
```

Comment: I added this line in my model `public bool ShowMessage { get; set; }`

Comment: So, in the model constructor I should set it as false right? And when `isValid` is true I should set `showMessage` to true. Am I making sense?

Comment: It's not necessary to set it to false in the constructor, bools default to false.  And you should set it to true only if the save succeeds, not if the form passes validation.  There could be some sort of error that fails to save the new password and you don't want to say it was changed if it wasn't.

Comment: Thank you so much! Appreciate it!

Comment: Currently, in orde to change the password I need to match the "Old Password" entered by the user to the one stored in DB. In case where oldpassword does not match I will have false as return value. But if I use that false to show "any error message" then this message will come as soon as the password reset windw opens (because by default its value will be false).

Comment: So as soon as I open the reset password window I will see a message that old password does not match (even though till now I have not given any try to reset the password)

Comment: So, How to populate the else part and still hide its visibility of error message when user has not tried to reset the password. he has just opened the reset password window.

Answer (score 0):

...

```
ViewBag.SaveResult=true;
return View(data);
```

.....
in view page

```
@if (ViewBag.SaveResult == true) {
<div class="alert alert-success" >             
<strong>Success! </strong>Your Password has been successfully changed.</div>


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this using `ValidationMessage`.

First in razor page add V`alidationMessage` for success and error:

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("ERROR", new { @class = "card-alert alert alert-danger v-message", @style = "display: none;" })
@Html.ValidationMessage("SUCCESS", new { @class = "card-alert alert alert-success v-message", @style = "display: none;" })
```

Then in controller you send error and success message using:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("SUCCESS", "Success message !");
ModelState.AddModelError("ERROR", "Error message !");
```

Add this code in JavaScript witch will display messages when needed:

```
$(".validation-message").each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() !== "") {
        $(this).css("display", "block");
    }
});
```